# Running tests located in a separate directory with mocha and ts-node?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js, typescript2.0, ts-node

I have source code and tests separated as follows:

```
`src/main/ts/hello.ts`  //SOURCE FILES HERE
`src/test/ts/hello.spec.ts` //SPEC FILES HERE
```

The import statement in `src/test/ts/hello.spec.ts` looks like this:

```
import hello from 'hello';
```

The `hello.ts` source code looks like this:

```
    export function hello() {
      return 'Hello World!';
    }

    export default hello;
```

My `tsconfig.json` is setup such that the test files can import source modules without using relative paths like this:

```
    {
       "include": [
         "src/main/ts/**/*.ts"
       ],
       "exclude": [
         "node_modules"
       ],

       "compilerOptions": {
         "experimentalDecorators": true,
         "noImplicitAny": true,
         "moduleResolution": "node",
         "target": "es6",
         "baseUrl": ".",
         "paths": {
           "*": [
             "*", "src/main/ts/*"
           ]
         }
       }
     }
```

This way the `hello.spec.ts` file can import `hello` using the statement `import hello from 'hello';`

I'm trying to run the tests with `npm test` configured to run mocha and tsnode like this (Based on [this article](https://journal.artfuldev.com/write-tests-for-typescript-projects-with-mocha-and-chai-in-typescript-86e053bdb2b6)):

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "mocha -r ts-node/register src/test/ts"
},
```

However it does not look like ts-node is picking up on my `tsconfig.json` configuration as I get this error:

> mocha -r ts-node/register src/test/ts

```
Error: Cannot find module 'hello'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The module resolution that you set through `paths` in `tsconfig.json` is purely an *compile-time thing*. (See this `ts-node` [issue report](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/138) and this TypeScript [issue report](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039) for details.) It does not affect how the code is emitted, which means that your test file is doing a `require("hello")`, which Node cannot resolve. The consequence of `paths` being a compile-time thing is that your module loader needs to be configured to *also* perform the same kind of resolution that you specify in `tsconfig.json`. If you were using RequireJS, for instance, you'd need to have a configuration for it that does the same thing `paths` in `tsconfig.json` does. You are using Node, however...

What you can do in Node is use [`tsconfig-paths`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths), which will read the `tsconfig.json`, parse the `paths` setting and change the module resolution in Node so that it works.

Using your code, I modified `hello.spec.ts` to have at least one test for feedback:

```
import hello from "hello";
import "mocha";

it("q", () => {
    if (hello() !== "Hello World!") {
        throw new Error("unequal");
    }
});
```

I installed `tsconfig-paths` and `@types/mocha` (so that `import "mocha"` does the right thing compilation-wise in the test file I show above) and invoked Mocha like this:

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/mocha --compilers ts:ts-node/register -r tsconfig-paths/register 'src/test/ts/**/*.ts'
```

I got this output:

```
  ✓ q

  1 passing (20ms)
```